# "Subscribing" to an announcements app part

Tags: sharepoint-online, alert, blog, notifications, announcements

I have an announcements app part that I use instead of a blog subsite. I would like to have a feature that would allow users to "subscribe" to the blog. I know there are alerts for lists and libraries but I would like mine to be a bit more like a YouTube subscribe button.

Currently my system is to have a button that opens a per-determined mailto: link that the user just presses send. I receive the email and add the user to a SharePoint group that follows a workflow to send an email to this group any time there is a new post in the announcements part.

I know there has to be a better way of going about this but I am quite the beginner at SharePoint. Thanks for any suggestions.